# Angular material - list with selection text truncate

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to use the Angular Material list with checkboxes but with text which needs to be truncated rather than word wrapped (due to UI space limitation). I have forked the example within the Angular Material site to show the problem. The text kinda truncates but not with an ellipse or as I was hoping/expecting. Could some css ninja help?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqk8h8

Looks like:
[image: No ellipsis]

I'm expecting each line to end with "..." before the checkbox.

I have the CSS of text-truncate: ellipsis and white-space: nowrap

Answer (score 0):

Changes required were a sub div as below

```
<div class="text">
Another example of quite long text which will need truncating on many screens
</div>
</div>
```

And adding the below css makes the overflow work

```
.content {
  display:flex;

}

.text {
  flex:1;
  min-width: 0px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```